# Underscore gets removed

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize removes the underscore in my foreign key.

`Role.belongsToMany(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', through: UserRole });`

Results in this:

`Unknown column 'UserRole.UserId' in 'field list'`

because the column is named user_id, and not UserId.

Even with the `underscore: true` option set, it does that.

Is there a way of solving this, it is driving me nuts because, I don't know if I am doing it wrong or sequelize is.

UserRole.js:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    roleId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      field: 'role_id',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      field: 'user_id',
      primaryKey: true
    }
  },
  associations: function() {
      UserRole.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
      UserRole.hasOne(Role, { foreignKey: 'id' });
  },
  options: {
    tableName: 'user_roles',
    timestamps: false,
    classMethods: {},
    instanceMethods: {},
    hooks: {}
  }
}
```

Role.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    },
  },
  associations: function() {
    Role.belongsToMany(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', through: UserRole });
  },
  options: {
    tableName: 'roles',
    timestamps: false,
    classMethods: {},
    instanceMethods: {},
    hooks: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've tried with the `underscore` option turned on? I don't see that in your code here and it's important.

Comment: @tadman I should probably sleep, forgot to add the `underscored` option to the User model. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Glad you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've enabled the `underscore` option in your models. If set Sequelize respects your naming convention preference and will link up things as expected.

I prefer the underscored names, long time Rails developer, and the mixed-case column names that result seem broken.